# Evaluate if int matches a defined enum type

Tags: objective-c, enums

I have an enum typedef containing several type definitions, eg:

```
ActionTypeSomething = 1,
ActionTypeSomethingElse = 2
```

And so on.

So a method I've written evaluates a passed int and then returns a value (for example, a string) accordingly.

```
(NSString *)evaluatAndReturnProperResult:(int)typeID

NSString *repsonseString;

switch (typeID) 
    case actionTypeSomething: {
        responseString = @"an appropriate string for typeID"
    }
...

return responseString;
```

So my switch evaluates each supported type and returns the correct string.

Now for my question:

I only want to return strings for supported types (i.e., in theory any integer could be passed). If there's no match, I return nil.

Obviously I can do this using exactly the method I already have. But could I (in theory) improve performance by evaluating the passed int to see if it matches *any* of my defined enum types BEFORE I send it through switch (the switch isn't massive, but I'd still rather just return nil at the beginning of the method if I know there's not going to be a match).

I'm sure this is easy, could someone suggest how to evaluate if my passed integer matches any define enum ActionType before I enter the switch? In this case I'm probably prematurely optimizing, but it's more of a general question about how to do achieve it (not if I should).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument for your method shouldn't be an int, it should ideally be the enum you have defined. This gives you some compile time checking.

If this is not possible then your default case in the switch will handle it just fine - that's what they are designed for.

Comment: Ideally yes - but in this case my method is sort of doing validation. A web service calls back with an array of entities, each entity having an int typeID. My UI is supposed to evaluate which of the entities are to be presented in the UI, which should only be those matching my enum  types. If I match, I return a string to display for the entity derived from the actionType. If I return nil, the ui-caller knows not to include that item in a table row. I just wondered if one could evaluate that without stepping through the switch. Thanks.

Comment: Then the second part of my answer works for you. Switches are super optimised AFAIK.

Comment: Indeed it does and thanks. Just wondered if there was another way out of curiosity, but there doesn't seem to be. Nice thing is I already have it working this way!

Answer (score 2):

You can define 2 more enum values:

```
typedef enum {
    ActionTypeMin = 1,
    ActionTypeSomething = 1,
    ActionTypeSomethingElse = 2,
    ActionTypeMax = 2
} ActionType;
```

Then check:

```
typeID >= ActionTypeMin && typeID <= ActionTypeMax
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using a TypeDef that's to limit ActionEnum to a set of values, so you shouldn't be using int in your program except for up or downstream communication. Some would say not even then and that you should recive a string and map it to the enum and vice versa.

In terms of getting your strings the usual optimsatiin is
Have an array of strings from ActionType1 to ActionTypeN.
Use the enum as the index to look it up from the array.

The array will also give you the doings to map the string to the enum.

A simple if statement of the enum cast as an integer against teh bound of the array will let you deal gracefully with a bad value, though to me that should throw a big blaring exception.

Comment: I'm not trying to limit them so much as have my UI cherry-pick which actionItems to present in the UI (and yeah, it's a web service giving me entities with defined action types that are ints). Because I'm dealing with far more int values than I'm concerned with an array with all of them would be much more than I need, but a dictionary keyed with only the types I'm interested is along the same line of thinking and I might give that a shot. Thanks!